# How to detect if Recyclerview item is being swiped?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add functionality of swipe to delete as well as to show bottom sheet pop-up if RecyclerView item is long pressed. I am using `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` for swipe to delete and `ItemTouchListener` for showing pop-up on long press of item.
**Problem is that when I am swiping the item to delete its also detecting long press.
What I want is that it should ignore long press when item is being swiped.** 
I have ItemTouchHelper class which extends Simplecallback for swipe to delete. Following is the code to attach recyclerview for swipe to delete.

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
    new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Follwing is code to add listener for long click event.

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new NotesRecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new NotesRecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Note note = notesList.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), note.getTitle() + " is log pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                View sheetView = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.view_bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
                BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(sheetView);
                dialog.show();
        }
    }));
```

Comment: What about adding a flag? When `onSwiped()` event is called, set a `swiped` flag to `true`. Then if the long click event is also fired, check the flag and if it's true, then it's during a swipe event, so do not execute the code in the long click, just exit the method. When the swipe event completes, reset the flag to false.

Comment: onSwiped() will be called after swiping is finished but I need to check if swiping is undergoing.

Comment: Oops, I meant `onChildDraw()` as suggested in the below answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidVelasquez has suggested you should set up a flag when swipe begins and act depending on it's state in your `onLongClick()` But `onSwiped()` is not the way to go. Instead you should use `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback#onChildDraw()` method to detect when the swipe beings and `onSwiped()` method to detect when it ends.

Eg.

```
override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int,isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
    if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
        setupMyFlag()
    }
}
override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
    clearMyFlag()
}
```

And then just check this flag in your onLongClick()

Comment: I did that in slightly different way. As my recyclerview is in MainActivity so I will not have access to childDraw()  so I declare an abstract method in ItemTouchHelper class and implement that method in mainActivity to get value of dX that is swipe displacement and then I used inside onLongClick() function if(dX <0){//do something on doubletap}. Thanks your answer has helped.

Comment: @Jan Stoltman This is not working both the methods are called onChildDraw() and also onSwiped. Any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

`onSwiped` will be called when item will be completely swiped. If you will start to swipe element but then move it back, the method will not be called. So you shouldn't use this method to mark the end of swiping.
You can use `isCurrentlyActive` from `onChildDraw` like this:

```
var swiping: Boolean = false

override fun onChildDraw(c: Canvas, recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, dX: Float, dY: Float, actionState: Int, isCurrentlyActive: Boolean) {
    super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
    if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
        swiping = isCurrentlyActive
    }
}
```

It will be true when you move element and false after swipe or cancelation of swipe.