# Swipe to reply in chat message like whats app programmatically in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, chat, swipe-gesture

I am currently working on chat application. I need swipe to reply a particular message like WhatsApp in android programmatically. kindly help me to achieve this. thanks in advance.

link I am referring
https://github.com/shainsingh89/SwipeToReply.

[image: swipe to reply]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here I will list the main challenges with the proposed solutions, you can find the entire project on the [github over here](https://github.com/M7mdZain/SwipeToReply):

## Challenge 1: New layouts with the quoted text

1. Adding two new chat message layouts for the sender & receiver `send_message_quoted_row` & `received_message_quoted_row` ->> The layout can just be better than that but it's not a big deal for now.
2. Modifying `MessageAdapter` to accept them as a new type, and update the quote text in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
    private fun getItemViewType(message: Message): Int {
        return if (message.type == MessageType.SEND)
            if (message.quotePos == -1) R.layout.send_message_row
            else R.layout.send_message_quoted_row
        else
            if (message.quotePos == -1) R.layout.received_message_row
            else R.layout.received_message_quoted_row
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messageList[position]
        holder.txtSendMsg.text = message.body
        holder.txtQuotedMsg?.text = message.quote
    }

    class MessageViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var txtSendMsg = view.txtBody!!
        var txtQuotedMsg: TextView? = view.textQuote
    }
```

3. Adding new constructor to the `Message` data class to accept the quote and the position of the original message (which is quoted in the current message

```
data class Message(var body: String, var time: Long, var type: Int) {

    var quote: String = ""
    var quotePos: Int = -1

    constructor(
        body: String,
        time: Long,
        type: Int,
        quote: String,
        quotePos: Int
    ) : this(body, time, type) {
        this.quote = quote
        this.quotePos = quotePos
    }

}

object MessageType {
    const val SEND = 1
    const val RECEIVED = 2
}
```

4. Adding sample quoted messages for testing in `SampleMessages`

## Challenge 2: Embed the quote layout into the reply layout animated like WhatsApp

In WhatsApp: the quote layout appears as a part of the reply layout, and it gradually comes from bottom to top behind the original layout. Also when the cancel button is pressed, it reverses the animation to the bottom.

- Solved by using a custom Animation class by changing the height of the quoted `TextView`, and then using View.Gone/Visible to show the layout.

```
class ResizeAnim(var view: View, private val startHeight: Int, private val targetHeight: Int) :
    Animation() {

    override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation) {
        if (startHeight == 0 || targetHeight == 0) {
            view.layoutParams.height =
                (startHeight + (targetHeight - startHeight) * interpolatedTime).toInt()
        } else {
            view.layoutParams.height = (startHeight + targetHeight * interpolatedTime).toInt()
        }
        view.requestLayout()
    }

    override fun willChangeBounds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

And handle this animation within the activity `showQuotedMessage()` & `hideReplyLayout()`

```
private fun hideReplyLayout() {

    val resizeAnim = ResizeAnim(reply_layout, mainActivityViewModel.currentMessageHeight, 0)
    resizeAnim.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION

    Handler().postDelayed({
        reply_layout.layout(0, -reply_layout.height, reply_layout.width, 0)
        reply_layout.requestLayout()
        reply_layout.forceLayout()
        reply_layout.visibility = View.GONE

    }, ANIMATION_DURATION - 50)

    reply_layout.startAnimation(resizeAnim)
    mainActivityViewModel.currentMessageHeight = 0

    resizeAnim.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            val params = reply_layout.layoutParams
            params.height = 0
            reply_layout.layoutParams = params
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
        }
    })

}

private fun showQuotedMessage(message: Message) {
    edit_message.requestFocus()
    val inputMethodManager =
        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(edit_message, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)

    textQuotedMessage.text = message.body
    val height = textQuotedMessage.getActualHeight()
    val startHeight = mainActivityViewModel.currentMessageHeight

    if (height != startHeight) {

        if (reply_layout.visibility == View.GONE)
            Handler().postDelayed({
                reply_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }, 50)

        val targetHeight = height - startHeight

        val resizeAnim =
            ResizeAnim(
                reply_layout,
                startHeight,
                targetHeight
            )

        resizeAnim.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION
        reply_layout.startAnimation(resizeAnim)

        mainActivityViewModel.currentMessageHeight = height

    }

}

private fun TextView.getActualHeight(): Int {
    textQuotedMessage.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    return this.measuredHeight
}
```

## Challenge 3: Calculating the real value of the new quoted text height

Especially when the quoted text height need to be expanded/shrink when the user swipes another message of a different height while there is currently a quoted message.

- Handled by using `getHeight()` function to programmatically inflate the quoted `TextView` and set its text to the new text, compare its height to the height of the old text, and manipulate the animation accordingly.
- This already covered in the top methods, and I tracked the old height in the ViewModel using `currentMessageHeight` integer.

## Challenge 4: Adding `OnClickListener` to the quoted message

- So to go to the original position of the quoted message, we registered this in the `Message` class as a field, when it's -1, then it's not a quoted message; otherwise it is a quoted message.
- The click listener is handled with a custom `QuoteClickListener` interface in the `MessageAdapter`

**Preview:**

[image]

Adding a new Message:

[image]

Comment: I am preparing the project to be on github, soon will add the repo

Comment: @Zain-let me try with this sample. thank you so much

Comment: @Kumar HYG [this is the forked github](https://github.com/M7mdZain/SwipeToReply) clone and enjoy.. Believe me this took me entire days to get it work

Answer (score 0):

You should read this for swipe to reply to chat messages hope it'll help you
https://medium.com/mindorks/swipe-to-reply-android-recycler-view-ui-c11365f8999f

Comment: same link only i am also referring its not as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/izjumovfs/SwipeToReply

try this and tell if it works

Comment: you can use https://stackoverflow.com/q/51617569/4598342 android class to detect gesture moves and accordingly change state of your EditText view in which you are typing message